# Copying Files Using NSBasic/CE 7.0

Tags: file-io, vbscript, windows-ce, nsbasic

I'm using [NSBasic/CE 7.0](http://nsbasic.com/ce) and I'm needing to copy a file, but I don't know how to copy using this program, but at the time I already have this:

```
AddObject "cecomdlg.commondialog.1", "ComSvDlg", 0, 0, 0, 0

Sub saveDialog()
  ComSvDlg.CancelError = 0
  ComSvDlg.DialogTitle = "Copy"
  ComSvDlg.Filter = "All Files|*.*"
  ComSvDlg.ShowSave
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    txtFileName = ComSvDlg.FileName
    MsgBox txtFileName
    ElseIf Err.Number = 32755 Then
      MsgBox "Canceled"
  End If
  KillFocus
End Sub

Sub mnuSave_Click
  saveDialog
  txtOutput.Text = ComSvDlg.FileName
End Sub
```

But one of the most important(copy) I don't know how to do. Could you help me to copy the file from `\test.txt` to `ComSvDlg.Filename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to information on the NS Basic/CE web site, it includes the following objects that provide the file system management functionality:

- [`FileSystem`](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/info/technotes/TN03e.htm)
- [`newObjects.utilctls.SFMain`](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/info/technotes/TN09.htm) (requires the [NewObjectsPack1.dll](http://www.newobjects.com/pages/ndl/axpack1/axpack1-main.htm) library)

To copy a file, you can use either the [`FileSystem.FileCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms857351.aspx) method or the [`SFMain.CopyFile`](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/info/technotes/TN09.htm#CopyFile.htm) method. The code should look like this (not tested, as I don't have NS Basic):

```
''# Using the FileSystem object
AddObject "FileSystem", "FS"
FS.FileCopy "\test.txt", ComSvDlg.FileName

''# Using the SFMain object
AddObject "newObjects.utilctls.SFMain", "FS"
FS.CopyFile "\test.txt", ComSvDlg.FileName
```